# How do I delete a question of mine?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

How do I remove a question? I have ask a few questions and I have gotten the answer either on here or an outside source, or the question wasn't understood so I have to rephrase it.  Anyways  I want to delete some of them now. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

If the question is an appropriate question that has gotten an answer then the question shouldn't be deleted at all.  If the question has any positively scored answers, or has multiple answers, then you *can't* delete it.  If you found the answer and nobody else has posted one, as long as the question is appropriate for the site, you should simply answer it, not delete it.

If a question wasn't well understood, and you need to rephrase it, then *edit the question* so that it is understandable.  You should only be deleting the question if there's nothing at all that you can do in order to turn it into an acceptable question.  If you are in that situation though, and your question is able to be deleted, then you can simply click the "delete" link under the question.